# ROS Consolor Color Print

Tags: ros, ros-info, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

Is there a way to change the color of what I print with ROS_INFO(), etc.?
I want to leave red and yellow for real errors and real warnings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242000/ros-consolor-color-print/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the colors are `#define`d here:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/98aa98e565ea623aae61c02f54ecb06c7ee190dd/tools/rosconsole/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.cpp#L103

I took just a brief glance and did not see any option for runtime configuration. Time to fork? :p

Or you could pipe the output to `sed` and replace the colors with a clever regex.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0